# Unable to hide scrollbar inside an iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have embedded an iframe n my page with content from another site.Here is a link if you want to visit it http://8mags.com/bored/wtf/wtf01.html
The problem is that I am unable to remove the scrollbars and a few other things.
My CSS code is here

```
html {
overflow-x: auto !important;
overflow-y: auto !important;
}
body {
overflow-y: auto !important;
background: white !important;
}
```

The problem is that scrollbar is still there.Also the background does not change to white inside iFrame.I also tried to hide a few details with this code

```
.quote-subtitle {
display: none !important;
}
```

but it does not work either.

**EDIT**

The code that produces the iFrame is this one

```
<span class="quora-content-embed" data-name="What-are-some-of-the-most-awesome-psychological-facts/answer/Arjun-Subramaniam/quote/2114886">Read <a data-width="541" data-height="893" class="quora-content-link" href="http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-of-the-most-awesome-psychological-facts/answer/Arjun-Subramaniam/quote/2114886" data-embed="nqjyswb" data-type="quote" data-id="2114886" data-key="78561af9adeb1d847ceae88107798254">Quote of Arjun Subramaniam's answer to What are some of the most awesome psychological facts?</a> on <a href="http://www.quora.com">Quora</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.quora.com/widgets/content"></script></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body class=" logged_out" style="overflow: hidden;">
```

i use this on link and worked,and hidden the scrollbars.
or use this to access content of iframe

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('body').css('overflow','hidden');
```

Comment: I have no control on the code inside iFrame so I can't put this code inline

Comment: The second part does not work either.It hides the scroll bar of my actual window but not the iFrame

Comment: use this $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('overflow','hidden'); to access content of ifram

Comment: Should i Place it inside the scripts tag in the head of my html code.

Comment: after <iframe> tag. in tag <script>

Comment: I am editing the question to add a little more detail.

Comment: Please take a look at the code that produces the iFrame.

Comment: @SeyedAshkufaraz for your solution to work: OP needs to use jQuery. Witch from the information given he isn't. Beyond this the iframe also needs to have the same origin or else the some browser may block that functionallity because of CORS.

Comment: Is the iframe src on another domain? Browser cross domain security will prevent you from changing its contents.

Comment: Yes the iframe src is from another domain. So, it means there is no way to change it.